# Yii2 Redirect on same page with data entered by user

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2-advanced-app. I've taken some actions on pop-up forms like this - [image: Pop-up action]

When we click on 'Create' button on pop-up, it creates some record & redirect us to the same page i.e. localhost/abcd/backend/web/index.php?r=xyz/create.
Here is the code I wrote for this -

```
public function actionCreateitem()
{
  $model = new Items();

  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['create', 'id' => $_SESSION['ro_id']]);
  } else {
    return $this->renderAjax('itemform', [
      'model' => $model,
      ]);
  }
}
```

Here I redirected the page on create form/page again. It's okay. But when user fills the whole form & then he wants to 'add item', he clicks on add button & create it on pop-up. But after submitting the pop-up form, all the fields on create page gets cleared which he recently filled(because we redirect it). ***I need the scenario where the page should not be refreshed/redirected after submitting the pop-up, it should remain on the same page, So that the data entered by the user will remain safe on the page.***
So, after creating an item, he will get the create page something like this -
[image: filled create form]

Comment: Have you tried sending the form using AJAX?

Comment: no, but please tell me a scenario. How will it be done ?

Comment: You can use jQuery for this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post There are plenty of examples all over the web so you shouldn't have any problems implementing it.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'll refer to it.

Comment: do I need to refresh the dropdown list after creating an item?

Comment: Yes, if you want the new one to be there. You can do it with AJAX as well.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way ***(All the new suggestions are also Welcome)***-

***add item pop-up-***

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$('#createitem').click(function() {
    var itemName = $('#items-item_name').val();
    var sku = $('#compitems-sku').val();
    var itemDesc = $('#items-item_description').val();
    $('#modalItem .close').click();
    $.get('?r=xyz/createitem&itemName='+itemName+'&sku='+sku+'&itemDesc='+itemDesc, function(success){
        $('.refreshitem').html(success);
    });
});");
?>
<div class="items-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'item_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($modelCI, 'SKU')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'item_description')->textArea(['rows' => 5]) ?>

    <div class="form-group"><p align="right">
        <button id="createitem" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button></p>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

***my select list & 'Add(+)' button on actual create form -***

```
<?= $form->field($model, "[{$i}]item_id")->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Items::find()->where(['deleted' => 'N'])->all(),'id','item_name'),['prompt'=>'Select Item', 'class' => 'form-control refreshitem']) ?>
<button id="modalButtonItem" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="?r=xyz/createitem&itemName=0&sku=0&itemDesc=0" onclick="itemModal(1);">+</button>
```

***controller method-***

```
public function actionCreateitem($itemName, $sku, $itemDesc)
{
  $model = new Items();
  $modelCI = new CompItems();
  if ($itemName != '0' && $sku != '0' && $itemDesc != '0') {
    $itemExist = Items::find()->select('id')->where(['item_name' => $itemName])->one();
    if(count($itemExist) == 0) {
      $model->item_name = isset($itemName) ? $itemName : 'NULL';
      $model->item_description = !empty($itemDesc) ? $itemDesc : $itemName;
      $model->save();
    }

    $items = Items::find()->where(['deleted' => 'N'])->all();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      echo '<option value="'.$item->id.'">'.$item->item_name.'</option>';
    }
  } else {
    return $this->renderAjax('itemform', [
      'model' => $model, 'modelCI' => $modelCI
      ]);
  }
}
```